# node.js app with nginx buildpack crashing at heroku

Tags: node.js, nginx, heroku, https, buildpack

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku with the intent to use 'nginx' as a front-end server to do some security checks before accepting the requests.

Followed all the steps from this URL - https://www.nodebeats.com/documentation/configuring-nginx-on-heroku

So, in the app, I have the following lines of code to start the server instance using nginx -

```
app.listen('/tmp/nginx.socket', function() {   
     if (process.env.DYNO) {
         console.log('This is on Heroku..!!');
         fs.openSync('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w');
      }
console.log('Node server started on ' + port + ' at ' + Date(new Date()));
});
```

The heroku has 2 buildpacks (node, nginx), downgraded the heroku stack from *heroku-16* to *cedar-14* to deploy the app successfully, created a proc file with

```
web: bin/start-nginx node example.js
```

, created config folder with *mime.types*, and *nginx.conf.erb* with the following details

```
http {
charset utf-8;
include mime.types;
 server {
    listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;      
    server_name  _;

    location / {
         proxy_pass https://example.herokuapp.com;           
    }       
 }
}
```

So, when I hit the app with the url - https://example.herokuapp.com, in heroku it throws the following error

```
[![error at heroku][1]][1] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPvvg.jpg
```

Any idea what's wrong with this implementation/configuration?

Does it have something to do with the fact that proxy_pass has https in uri?

Comment: every get this sorted?